# Setting up to use JAVAFX at the Command Line

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I am experimenting with FXML.  Here is the java file.   It resides in /Users/morrison/teaching/java/xml and all files have read permission.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
public class Example extends Application
{
    private Stage primary;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primary) 
    {
        this.primary = primary;
        Parent root = null;
        try
        {
            File f = new File("/Users/morrison/teaching/java/xml/");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(f.toURI().toURL());
            System.out.println(loader.getLocation());
            root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("Example.fxml"));
            primary.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
            primary.setTitle("FXML Example");
            primary.show();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){System.err.println("file cant be found");}
    }
}
```

Here is the `.fxml` file, which resides in the same directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <top>
        <HBox>
            <Button text="Go!" onAction="#handleGo" fx:id="goButton"/>
            <Button text="Stop!" onAction="#handleStop" fx:id="stopButton"/>
        </HBox>
    </top>
    <center>
        <canvas fx:id="colorField">
        </canvas>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

When I run this, I am being told the FXML file can't be found.
Is there some other piece I am missing?

Comment: Experiment conducted.   The location points directly at the file-s directory.

Comment: I printed these lines      System.out.println(loader.getLocation());
            System.out.println(getClass().getResource("Example.fxml").getPath());

Comment: output:   file:/Users/morrison/teaching/java/xml/
/Users/morrison/teaching/java/xml/Example.fxml

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: All files in the same directory.

Comment: Ah so there is no resources directory?  `getClass().getResource(...)` is looking in the resource directory not the main project directory